# I'm looking for a feature id without going through a for or while cycle

Tags: openlayers, features

I'm trying to find some land from a previous vector layer loaded with geojson from the geoserver.

I have a way to search:

This method goes through each field in my vector layer and compares the ids between them and where it finds results, the function operates:

```
imobile.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
                
      console.log(feature.getProperties());
});
```

Console returns:

> ```
> > e_terra: "73915" geometry: e {disposed_: false, pendingRemovals_: {…},
> > dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, revision_: 2, …} id_primarie: 26
> > layer: "TEREN" parcela: "3082" proprietari: "COMUNA SILIȘTEA--"
> > suprafata: "429252" tarla: "145" text: 6099
> > __proto__: Object
> ```

That "text" is the id of the field polygon now I would like to find that id without going through that search cycle above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get individual feature from vector layer source by source method `.getFeatureById`. If in your GeoJSON data each feature has an `id`, it's automatically assigned to the feature id in OL, and consequently you can get it by the above mentioned method.

If you want to have direct access to individual features by some other unique GeoJSON feature property, you can assign it to the feature id by feature `.setId` method, getting the value of property by feature `.get` method.

In your case you would run this loop only once:

```
imobile.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
  feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
});
```

Then you could get your desired feature for example by:

```
var feature = imobile.getSource().getFeatureById(6099);
```